# How to find files that match names in a list and copy them to a directory?

Tags: unix, find, cp

I have a list of 50 names that look like this:

```
    O8-E7
    O8-F2
    O8-F6
    O8-F8
    O8-H2
    O9-A5
    O9-B8
    O9-D8
    O9-E2
    O9-F5
    O9-H12
    S37-A5
    S37-B11
    S37-B12
    S37-C12
    S37-D12
    S37-E8
    S37-G2
```

I want to look inside a specific directory for all the subdirectories whose name contains one of these elements.
For example, the directory `Sample_S37-G2-from-Specimen-001` would be a match.

Inside those subdirectories, there is a file called accepted_hits.bam (unfortunately named the same way in all of them). I want to find these files and copy them into a single folder, with the name of the sample subdirectory that they came from.

For example, I would copy the `accepted_hits.bam` file from the subdirectory `Sample_S37-G2-from-Specimen-001` to the new_dir as `S37-G2_accepted_hits.bam`

I tried using find, but it's not working and I don't really understand why.

```
cat sample.list | while read FILENAME; do find /path/to/sampleDirectories -name "$FILENAME" -exec cp '{}' new
_dir\; done
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for dirs that are exactly the same as the lines in your input.
The first improvement would be using wildcards

```
cat sample.list | while read FILENAME; do
   find /path/to/sampleDirectories -name "*${FILENAME}*" -exec cp '{}' new_dir\; done
```

Your new problem is that now you will be looking for dir's, not files. You want to find dir's with the filename accepted_hits.bam.
So your next try would be parsing the output of

```
   find /path/to/sampleDirectories -name accepted_hits.bam | grep "${FILENAME}"
```

but you do not want to call find for each entry in sample.list.
You need to start with 1 find command and get the relevant subdirs from it.
A complication is that you want to have the substring from orgfile in your destfile name. Look at the grep options o and f, they help!

```
find /path/to/sampleDirectories -name accepted_hits.bam | while read orgfile | do
   matched_part=$(echo "${orgfile}" | grep -of sample.list)
   if [ -n "${matched_part}" ]; then
      cp ${orgfile} newdir/${matched_part}accepted_hits.bam
   fi
done
```

This will only work when your sample.list is without additional spaces. When you have spaces and can not cange the file, you need to copy/parse sample.list to another file.
When one of your 50 entries in sample.list is a substring of "accepted_hits.bam", you need to do some extra work.

Edit: `if [ -n "${matched_part}" ]` was missing the `$`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it and it does exactly what I need; the only problem I encountered is that the `if [-n "matched_part"]` statement is not `FALSE` when the `${orgfile}` has no match in the samples file. I'm not sure why this is, but the result is that it keeps copying and overwriting thousands of `.bam` files as` _accepted_hits.bam` as it reads through the results of `find` until it finds something that matches...

Comment: Edited my answer. Of course the fixed string "matched_part" was always filled.

Answer (score 0):

Try using egrep with alternation

1. build a text file with single line of patterns: `(pat1|pat2|pat3)`
2. call find to list all of the regular files
3. use egrep to select the ones based on the patterns in the pattern file

   `awk 'BEGIN { printf("(") }    FNR==1  {printf("%s", $0)}    FNR>1   {printf("|%s", $0)}   END{printf(")\n") } ' sample.list > t.sed`

   `find /path/to/sampleDirectories  -type f | egrep -f t.sed > filelist`